# Receiving Error Property validation failure: [Value of property {/TableInput/ViewOriginalText} does not match type {String}] AWS cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am trying to create external view using the data from the tables but receiving error Property validation failure: [Value of property {/TableInput/ViewOriginalText} does not match type {String}] while creating views in AWS glue using cloud formation.

Any idea about resolution would be appreciated. Below is the yaml file code snippet that I am using.

Thanks in Advance

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: "Glue Athena database and table configuration"
Parameters:

  MarketingAndSalesDatabaseName:
    Type: String
    MinLength: "4"
    Default: "marketingandsales_qs"
    Description: "Name of the AWS Glue database to contain this CloudFormation template's tables."

  SalesPipelineTableName:
    Type: String
    MinLength: "4"
    Default: "salespipeline_qs"
    Description: "Name of the Sales Pipeline data table in AWS Glue."

Resources:

  ### AWS GLUE RESOURCES ###

  MarketingAndSalesDatabase:
    Type: "AWS::Glue::Database"
    Properties:
      DatabaseInput:
        Description: "Marketing and Sales database (Amazon QuickSight Samples)."
        Name: !Ref MarketingAndSalesDatabaseName
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId

  SalesPipelineTable:
    Type: "AWS::Glue::Table"
    DependsOn: MarketingAndSalesDatabase
    Properties:
      TableInput:
        Description: "Sales Pipeline table (Amazon QuickSight Sample)."
        TableType: "VIRTUAL_VIEW"
        Parameters: {
                "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
                "compressionType": "none",
                "classification": "csv",
                "recordCount": "16831",
                "typeOfData": "file",
                "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0",
                "columnsOrdered": "true",
                "objectCount": "1",
                "delimiter": ",",
                "skip.header.line.count": "1",
                "averageRecordSize": "119",
                "sizeKey": "2002910",
                "presto_view": "true"
        }
        StorageDescriptor:
          StoredAsSubDirectories: False
          Parameters: {
                  "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
                  "compressionType": "none",
                  "classification": "csv",
                  "recordCount": "16831",
                  "typeOfData": "file",
                  "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0",
                  "columnsOrdered": "true",
                  "objectCount": "1",
                  "delimiter": ",",
                  "skip.header.line.count": "1",
                  "averageRecordSize": "119",
                  "sizeKey": "2002910"
          }
          InputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat"
          OutputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
          Columns:
            - Type: string
              Name: salesperson
            - Type: string
              Name: lead_name
        ViewOriginalText:
          'Fn::Sub':
            - '/* Presto View: ${View} */'
            - View:
                 'Fn::Base64': !sub '{"catalog": "awsdatacatalog",
                                  "schema":"default",
                                  "columns": [ { "name": "salesperson", "type": "varchar" }, { "name": "lead_name", "type": "varchar" }],
                                  "originalSql": "SELECT salesperson AS salesperson, lead_name AS lead_name FROM marketing_qs_1"
                  }'
        Retention: 0
        Name: !Ref SalesPipelineTableName
      DatabaseName: !Ref MarketingAndSalesDatabaseName
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
```

Answer (score 0):

These properties should be underneath [`StorageDescriptor`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-table-storagedescriptor.html) instead of [`ViewOriginalText`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-table-tableinput.html#cfn-glue-table-tableinput-vieworiginaltext):

```yaml
          Compressed: False
          Location: !Sub "s3://${DataBucketName}/sales/"
```

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates:

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

`[cfn-lint] E3002: Property is an object instead of String at Resources/SalesPipelineTable/Properties/TableInput/ViewOriginalText`

[`Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) also isn't required inside that [`Base64`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-base64.html):

`[cfn-lint] W1020: Fn::Sub isn't needed because there are no variables at Resources/SalesPipelineTable/Properties/TableInput/ViewOriginalText/Fn::Sub/1/View/Fn::Base64/Fn::Sub`

Comment: Edited the new code for your reference in the original post

Comment: Thanks @pat for your reply, I have fixed those issues by using cfn-lint. I am facing new issue E3002 Property should be of type String not List at Resources/SalesPipelineTable/Properties/TableInput/ViewOriginalText. Sorry, I am a newbie in these cloudformation scripts so I could not find the resolution for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @John think I might've confused you with the extra comment about [`Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) because now too much has been removed from [`ViewOriginalText`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-table-tableinput.html#cfn-glue-table-tableinput-vieworiginaltext). The original [`ViewOriginalText`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-table-tableinput.html#cfn-glue-table-tableinput-vieworiginaltext) should be fine

Comment: Thanks @Pat for your reply. I have made those changed and posted in the original post. cfn-lint does not show any errors but cloud formation says the YAML is not well formed. Can you look at it and figure why it is throwing me an error,
Thanks in Advance!